# How to handle redirects to versioned content?

Tags: seo, redirects, search-engines, versioning

Given the situation that

`docs.foo.com/2.9` is the documentation for a product, revision `2.9` and
`docs.foo.com/3.0` is the documentation for a product, revision `3.0`

Then you might want another URL

`docs.foo.com/latest` that redirects to `docs.foo.com/3.0`, until revision `3.1` launches. When the newer version becomes available, it should then lead to `docs.foo.com/3.1`.

Should `docs.foo.com/latest` be a 301 redirect with Cache-Control `no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`?

Search engines are supposed to index `docs.foo.com/2.9`, `.../3.0` etc., and it would be nice if they recognized `.../latest` as the most relevant one and therefore favor `.../3.0` over `.../2.9`, and later `.../3.1` over the former two.

Does `docs.foo.com/latest` require additional configuration? Like, should it be disallowed to be indexed directly per `robots.txt`, or is there a special header that can be set to indicate that this is redirect that refers to the latest version of some content?

There is also the problem that currently `docs.foo.com` is equivalent to `docs.foo.com/2.9`, but `docs.foo.com` then changed and became equivalent to `docs.foo.com/3.0`. The `3.0` version has a different structure of its sub pages, so that 404 errors error.

Can `docs.foo.com` be made equivalent to `docs.foo.com/latest`, so that it also redirects to the latest version, e.g. `docs.foo.com/3.1` and search engines be forced to update their indexes to prevent 404 errors if you follow obsolete `docs.foo.com` links (which were meant to refer to `2.9`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you 301 redirect an URL then the search engine will merge the records on it's end. Your /latest is filed under /3.0, which is what it will index. This not only prevents /latest being a static resource request but prevents it from even appearing in search.

According to best practices, duplicate content must be canonically linked. This means your latest version page has to canonically link to the /latest URI. You'll have to add a rel=canonical ->/latest to the newest version page. Then remove it and place it in the next version when you upgrade. This means /3.0 won't be indexed until it's superseded because the search engine has merged records into /latest. When /latest is drawing from /3.1, it will have to re-index /3.0.

Comment: Regarding the canonical link: I assume every page of the currently latest version of the content should link to its /latest counterpart? Or is it enough to link to the base address `docs.foo.com/latest/`?

Comment: Every page has to have it's mirror in a canonical link.